# Create a user with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a user from another model (Corporacion),
I wrote this in the Corporacion model:

```
after_create :createUser

def createUser
    @user = Usuario.create(nombre: "aa", corp_id: 3, email: "aa@aa", password: 123456, password_confirmation: 123456, rol: 3)
    @user.save
end
```

But when I create a Corporacion the user is not created (Im using rails 4.1 and ruby 1.9.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `create` saves valid objects. So you don't need to call `save` after that. But we know its not being saved. First suspicion is a validation error.

To debug your saving you may use `create!` method instead of `create`. It will raise exception if your saving will fail. But using of `create!` as well as other "bang" methods is not very good practice. So I can't suggest you to use it in your production code.

And one more tip in case if `create!` works and `create` doesn't:
Best practice to perform creation in your use case is something like following:

```
def createUser
  user = Usuario.new(nombre: "aa", corp: self, email: "aa@aa", password: 123456, password_confirmation: 123456, rol: 3)
  user.save ? true : user.errors
end
```

That code will return successfull result (`true`) if your `user` was created and validation errors occurred if not. So with that you'll be able to handle your errors properly in the code which calls `createUser`. And also it will expose why your saving doesn't work now.

Comment: That was my mystake tiping, but is not the error, sorry

Comment: Hold on. It's not very good practice to use `create!` and other "bang" methods in your production code. It maybe useful for debugging however. So you better find out why your simple `create` didn't work. Still think the deal is your `Corporacion` don't exist at the time whe you create `User`.

Comment: I tried to create the user after saving Corporation but it is also ignored, but when I use "!" it works

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer again with the best practice for object creation. Check it out. Sorry for multiple updates, I'm a bit distracted now but want to help:)

Comment: If I try that the model goes into a loop because it tries to create a Corporacion after creating a Corporacion (Remember that the function is within the Corporacion model)

Comment: Sure, it's the callback! Thanks for the prompt! What can I say:) Check my another answer update. Should work perfect now! I guess:)